# how to replace part of a string using sed

Tags: regex, sed

```
echo "/home/repository/tags/1.9.1/1.9.1.8/core" | sed "s/HELP/XXX/g"
```

I would like some HELP in replacing what is in between tags and core with let's say XXX.  So my desired output would be /home/repository/tags/XXX/core.

The string is a directory path, where /home/repository/tags are the only constant parts. The path is always six levels deep.  So it may not always be between tags and core.

Comment: To clarify: You want to always replace the fourth and fifth components of the path with a specific string?

Comment: Yes - and i might as well say maybe more than six components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using repetition quantifiers, you can easily adjust where your replacement is made:

```
echo "/home/repository/tags/1.9.1/1.9.1.8/core" | \
    sed -r 's|(/([^/]+/){3})([^/]+/){2}(.*)|\1XXX/\4|'
```

- 3 represents how many components to keep at the beginning
- 2 represents how many to replace

You could even use variables:

```
$ dirs='/one/two/three/four/five/six/seven/eight'
$ for keep in {0..3}; do for replace in {0..3}; do echo "$dirs" | \
    sed -r "s|(/([^/]+/){$keep})([^/]+/){$replace}(.*)|\1XXX/\4|"; done; done
/XXX/one/two/three/four/five/six/seven/eight
/XXX/two/three/four/five/six/seven/eight
/XXX/three/four/five/six/seven/eight
/XXX/four/five/six/seven/eight
/one/XXX/two/three/four/five/six/seven/eight
/one/XXX/three/four/five/six/seven/eight
/one/XXX/four/five/six/seven/eight
/one/XXX/five/six/seven/eight
/one/two/XXX/three/four/five/six/seven/eight
/one/two/XXX/four/five/six/seven/eight
/one/two/XXX/five/six/seven/eight
/one/two/XXX/six/seven/eight
/one/two/three/XXX/four/five/six/seven/eight
/one/two/three/XXX/five/six/seven/eight
/one/two/three/XXX/six/seven/eight
/one/two/three/XXX/seven/eight
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "/home/repository/whatever/1.9.1/1.9.1.8/core/and/more/junk"   \
| sed 's@\(/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*\)/[^/]*/[^/]*@\1/XXX@'
```

yields ...

```
/home/repository/whatever/XXX/core/and/more/junk
```

Comment: I like the @ as separator.  I always forget you can do that.  Your solution is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

If your directory is always 6 levels deep, this works (remember to escape the round brackets):

```
echo "/home/repository/tags/1.9.1/1.9.1.8/core" | 
sed 's/\(\/home\/repository\/tags\/\).*\/.*\(\/.*\)/\1XXX\2/'
```

produces:

```
/home/repository/tags/XXX/core
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, spare yourself some regex agony:

```
echo "/home/repository/tags/1.9.1/1.9.1.8/core" | sed 's@/home/repository/tags/.*/\(.\+\)$@/home/repository/tags/XXX/\1@'
```

No need to explicitly match the components if all you're really trying to do is strip out everything between `tags/` and the last component. Note that I used `+` not `*`, so the component must be nonempty. That'll guard against having a trailing slash.